# Counting days in a product life excluding the summers

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2000

I am trying to write an ms access SQL query in order to calculate the number of days that have passed since a date in two year periods: "summer" (from 1/6 to 30/09) and non-summer (from 1/1 to 30/05 and from 1/10 to 31/12).

This date is the last "measure" of the product and it could be as old as two years. 
Then I would like to know, as today, how many days of summer and vice-versa how many days of nonsummer has passed since the product has been measured.

ie. the date is 31/10/2017, I'd like two columns to show summer days passed (=30days*4months in 2018+ 28days in 2019 = 148days) and non-summer days passed ( 7months between Nov17 and may17+ 8 months from Ott18 to May 19 = 450days)

I have been trying using IIF cycles like that one:
(ANNI is a variable that means in which year we are 0=this year, 1 past year, etc)

days of non-summer

```
IIF(ANNI=0; "150"; IIF(ANNI=1;   
IIF(G2.DATA_PRODUZ<#01/06/2018#;DateDiff("d",[G2]! 
[DATA_PRODUZ],#01/06/2018#)+90+150;                              
IIF(G2.DATA_PRODUZ>#30/08/18#;DateDiff("d",[G2]! 
[DATA_PRODUZ],#31/12/2018#)+150));"etc");)
```

But it won't work and it does it would only work this summer. I'd accept any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the most efficient method, but certainly the most readable might be to define a VBA function (in a public module) such as:

```
Function SummerDays(ByVal dateFrom As Date, ByVal dateTo As Date) As Long
    While dateFrom < dateTo
        If dateFrom >= DateSerial(Year(dateFrom), 6, 1) And dateFrom <= DateSerial(Year(dateFrom), 9, 30) Then
            SummerDays = SummerDays + 1
        End If
        dateFrom = dateFrom + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

And then call this from your query:

```
SummerDays(G2.DATA_PRODUZ, Date())
```

Then, for the non-summer days, you could either define another function with an inverse `if` statement, or subtract the number of summer days from the total number of days between the two dates, e.g.:

```
DateDiff("d",G2.DATA_PRODUZ, Date()) - SummerDays(G2.DATA_PRODUZ, Date())
```

---

To create a public module in which to define the above function:

- Open the VBA IDE using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Insert a new public module by going to `Insert > Module` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>
- Copy the above function definition into the Module, below the `Option` statements.
- Save the Module with an appropriate name.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. I understood the logic behind what you wrote, i am only struggling implementing the vba code and calling it from the query, as i never worked with vba and i have to learn it. I have created a public module with your summerdays code, but when i try to implement it in the sql code, i get an error saying "Function "SummerDays" not defined in the expression". I'll post the whole query in the main post now.

Comment: @GiacomoRabino since you are new to VBA, I have added some instructions to my answer describing how to create a public module to house the function definition.

Comment: Thanks man, now it works. You really helped me, i hope to learn fast vba as it seems it could really juice up my sql code. cheers